How to correctly compose an ascending passage in the harmonic minor scale while avoiding the augmented second between the 6th and 7th scale degrees?
In classical harmony, we're often taught to avoid augmented intervals. The problem arises when harmonizing an ascending passage in the harmonic minor scale, where an augmented second appears between the 6th and 7th scale degrees (e.g., F-G# in A harmonic minor).

Does it mean that such a passage is incorrect from harmonic point of view?
Or maybe there are exception to avoid augmented intervals rule? Is this one of this exceptions?
Shall we always use melodic minor when composing a melody with such a passage?


'Harmonic' reflects its use - harmonically, and 'melodic' reflects its use melodically. The 'rules' are only there as guidelines, and then mainly from a classical standpoint. Composing these days gives far more leeway.

As a hobby I study classical harmony so I am wondering what would be the correct answer in Wien in middle of XVIII century ;) So I understand that a passage should rather go with the melodic scale.


The problem arises when harmonizing an ascending passage in the harmonic minor scale...


I am wondering what would be the correct answer in Wien in middle of XVIII century.

In Vienna in the eighteenth century, you would never find anyone harmonizing an ascending passage in the harmonic minor scale.
The three forms of the minor scale were identified somewhat later than that.  I am not certain when this happened, but I do know that music treatises of the 18th century do not discuss forms of the minor scale.
My sense is that the forms of the scale were devised at some point in the nineteenth century as pedagogical methods such as Czerny's, based in part on the repetition of various scales and similar patterns, progressing chromatically up or down with each repetition.  For major-tonality exercices, this is fairly straightforward, but for minor scales you have the problem that the "nominal" minor scale, now known as the natural minor, doesn't actually reflect compositional practice; most pieces in minor keys will use nine pitch classes instead of seven.  This is because the sixth and seventh scale degrees are often chromatically altered -- raised by a semitone -- in different contexts.  But arranging all nine pitch classes into a single scale also doesn't reflect compositional practice, so someone devised these two additional "versions" of the minor scale.  You can practice them, and they are rather closer to actual compositional practice, but they still don't reflect it entirely faithfully; they are something of a simplified model.
Importantly, no piece is in a "harmonic minor" key or "melodic minor" key.  Minor-key pieces are just in minor keys, period.  They will sometimes use the raised sixth or seventh degree and sometimes the unaltered.  This is reflected in the direction-dependent definition of the melodic minor scale, where if you take the two directions together, you do get all nine pitch classes.  But still, this is a simplified model.  You do sometimes see descending figures using the raised sixth and seventh degrees or ascending figures using the unaltered.
The harmonic scale is so called because you will see this particular set of pitch classes in, most notably, the iv-V-i cadence, where the minor subdominant includes the unaltered sixth degree, and the dominant includes the raised seventh degree.  But you'll never see both of those in the same voice m because, as you note, the melodic augmented second is generally not accepted.  Instead, one voice will have, if the key is A minor, F-E-E while another has A-G♯-A.

Does it mean that such a passage is incorrect from harmonic point of view?

If you do have such a melody, it would sooner be called a fault of voice leading or counterpoint than of harmony.  If done skillfully, most likely in an inner voice, it would be "unusual" or "expressive" rather than a "fault."

Or maybe there are exception to avoid augmented intervals rule? Is this one of this exceptions?

Not really.  I expect that actual genius composers probably did write a handful of instances of this sort of thing, but these will likely be an expressive bending of the rules rather than an exception.

Shall we always use melodic minor when composing a melody with such a passage?

You should not focus on a particular minor scale but on the idiomatic harmonic progressions of minor tonality, from which the scales were (somewhat artificially) derived.

In the Common Practice Period, composers thought of music as (mainly) having a major or minor mode. The notes of these modes could be arranged in order by pitch, and yielding scales, but scales were not the primary organization.
Major keys have the pattern (using C as the tonic) C-D-E-F-G-A-B; minor keys differ in that the third lowest note is a minor third above the tonic, C-D-Eb-F-G-Ab-Bb. The other difference in treating minor-mode pieces is that the 6th and 7th scale steps are mutable. One may replace either with the note a half-step above without causing a (temporary) displacement of the tonic.
Composers (popular, "serious," amateur, etc.) have commonly used three combinations of the mutable tones in the same piece, sometimes in the same measure. Using the lower (I don't like to use the terms "sharp," "natural," or "flat" here as these words have other connotations) version of the 7th step and lower version of the 6th seems to indicate a major key on another tonic.
There are a few preferences in use, but none are a majority.
In a passage with primarily subdominant harmony, the lower form of both notes is common.
In a passage with primarily dominant harmony, the upper form of both notes is common.
In ascending passages with tonic harmony, the upper form of both notes is common. In descending passages with tonic harmony, the lower form of both notes is common. (Thus the term "melodic minor.")
Harmonies are often built using a minor tonic chord, a minor subdominant chord, and a major dominant chord. The minor chord on the dominant is commonly used in non-cadential locations. (No cadence means no real need to have the half step from the 7th step to the tonic.)
Composers use the "harmonic minor" (lower 6th step, upper 7th) anywhere. It stands out melodically.
Two other common practices are:

the upper form of step 6 is never used as the upper neighbor to step 5. Likewise the lower form of step 7 is not usually found as the lower neighbor to step 1. (Composers like half-step neighbors.)
The augmented chord on the minor third (Eb-G-B in the key of C minor) is rare until the last part of the 19th century.

I usually use the upper and lower forms of mutable notes as described in bass lines but the "harmonic" minor in melodies. I like the sound.
These few practices are easy to include even in improvisations.

"How to correctly compose an ascending passage in the harmonic minor scale while avoiding the augmented second between the 6th and 7th scale degrees?"
Your question is self-contradictory.   'An ascending passage in the harmonic minor scale' will have the augmented 2nd interval between ^6 and ^7. (Come to that, so will a descending one.)  Smooth it out if you wish, but then you won't be using the harmonic minor scale any more.
Do I detect a misapprehension that there's some 'rule' that a piece should stick to using just one form of the minor scale?  Not so.  Not now, not ever.
